# Get input box value to another input box with conditions

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I am trying to pass a value from a textbox to another textbox (Same window) with conditions, Lets say. If the value from the first textbox is 1 then the output on the other textbox will be 2, and if the first textbox is 2 then the output on the other will be 3 and so on so forth.

Here is what Ive done so far.
Text box 1:

```
<input type="text" name="basic_salary"  value="<?php
if ($emp_salary->basic_salary <= 15999) {
echo $emp_salary->provident_fund = 120;
 } elseif ($emp_salary->basic_salary >= 16000) {
 echo $emp_salary->provident_fund = 1;
   } else {
    echo "Have a good night!";
}
 ?>"  class="form-control">
```

and for the textbox 2:

```
<label class="control-label" >SSS </label>
 <input type="text" name="provident_fund"  value="<?php
  if (!empty($emp_salary->provident_fund)) {
  echo $emp_salary->provident_fund;
  }
  ?>"  class="form-control">
```

am using Codeigniter. Thank you!

Comment: First of all, on the first `<input>` you are `echo`ing an assignment? How does that work? But regardless of that, I don't see how your requirement meets whatever your code is doing... basically if input 1 is x, input 2 is x+1, that's what you're saying. The code does... well, nothing like that... In any case I see you're modifying the internal status of the object, so I kinda get the idea over there, I just seriously don't know what you're trying to do. Maybe if you give us (or me) a concrete example of what it should actually do, we (or I) might be able to help.

Comment: uhm okay. Actually what I am trying to accomplish is there will be a range of set that whatever is typed in input 1 will have a corresponding output on input 2. Like for example
if input 1 is <= 10 , input 2 = a
if input 1 is <=20 , input 2 = b
if input 1 is <=30, input 3 = c

something like that

Comment: Ok, so basically input`N` depends on the value of input`N-1`. Is that correct? Having an initial input`1` to start with. I think I get it now. By the way, are `basic_salary` and `provident_fund` public?. So as far as it goes, I just wonder what's the error or issue that you're getting, I mean, what are you expecting to see that you're not seeing when you run the code? (Sounds stupid, but I want to know if there's a fatal error, or "Have a good night!" shows up or whatever the case it may be, just to see where to tweak the code). Maybe it's a class issue, maybe not.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in the controller before passing the data to the view.

```
// defaults
$content_data['basic_salary'] = $emp_salary->basic_salary;
$content_data['provident_fund'] = "";

// exception(s) - can be expanded
if ($emp_salary->basic_salary  <= 15999) {
    $content_data['provident_fund'] = 120;
}elseif ($emp_salary->basic_salary >= 16000) {
    $content_data['provident_fund'] = 1;
}

$this->load->view('content', $content_data);
```

Then in your view do something like

```
<input type="text" name="basic_salary" value="<?php echo $basic_salary; ?>">
<input type="text" name="provident_fund" value="<?php echo $provident_fund; ?>">
```

Might need some tuning from your side.